# Cloudbees Lift ClickStart pom.xml jetty dependency?

Tags: cloudbees

[CloudBees Lift template pom.xml](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/lift_template/blob/master/pom.xml) specifies Jetty as a dependency, even though Jetty is not available for Cloudbees yet.  Is that just leftover from a boilerplate pom.xml, or is it required for something?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.22</version>
    <configuration>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fork https://github.com/CloudBees-community/lift_template, try the clickstart without this dependency, and create a pull-request if you successfully got it deployed without this dependency

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a left over from lift - we can run jetty now via plain JVM apps, if that is what is preferred (however a new clickstart will be needed).

http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary when running your application on CloudBees, but it would allow you to run it locally, should you want to.